# Существует ли метод преобразования объекта Date в объект LocalDatetime?

Tags: java, дата

Существует ли метод преобразования объекта Date в объект LocalDatetime или LocalDate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отдельно метода нет, но можно воспользоваться `Instant` и сделать так:

```
Instant now = new Date().toInstant(); 
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(now,ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Или так:

```
Instant now = new Date().toInstant(); 
LocalDateTime ldt = now.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
```